# CAKEPHP 3 : Select * and sum() in one statement

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to fetch result from database table with SELECT * and SUM() function.
The sql query is :

> SELECT * ,SUM(msg_send) AS `msg_send` FROM `msg_campaigns`

Now how to write this query in cakephp3.

I am trying this :

```
$this->loadModel('MsgCampaigns');  
$SmsDetails = $this->MsgCampaigns->find('all',[ 
'conditions'=>['YEAR(date_time)'=>date('Y')],
'fields'=>['msg_send'=>'SUM(msg_send)','msg_failed'=>'SUM(msg_failed)']
]);
```

But I do not know how to use SELECT * . Please help

Answer (score 2):

Check the CakePHP Query Builder on [how to use SQL functions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions) and [how to select all fields](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-all-fields-from-a-table).

```
$query = $this->MsgCampaigns->find();
$query
    ->select([
        'sum_msg_send' => $query->func()->sum('msg_send'),
        'sum_msg_failed' => $query->func()->sum('msg_failed')
    ])
    // passing the table instance to the `select` function, selects all fields
    ->select($this->MsgCampaigns);

$query->execute();
```